# Centering divs inside of a div

Tags: html, center, css

I have a div that is 100% wide that contains a number og smaller div's "100x100px".

But I would like them to be centered so that there always is the same amount of space on the left and right side when they are forced to start on a new row.
Am I going around this the wrong way?

CSS:

```
.menuContainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #7144E0;
}
    .menuItem {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #F3FD4F;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menuContainer">
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
    <div class="menuItem"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/yofu4md0/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` rule to `.menuContainer`

```
.menuContainer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #7144E0;
    text-align:center; /* Added this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yofu4md0/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
text-align: center;
```

in menuContainer.

**LIVE DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/yofu4md0/4/

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't do exactly this, but in the project I have open right now I use two divs to center all content on the page, which look like this:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hopefully this can help you. I don't think text-align:center is necessary.

Just looked at that demo as well, looks cool :D